# Update ZenDesk ticket using AJAX Chrome Extension

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, zendesk-api

From the agent view in zendesk I want to inject code to update a zendesk ticket but I am not sure if that is possible without authentication? Right now I am trying this but getting a 'Forbidden Response'

Not sure if anyone has some insight on this?

```
"request": {
    "comment": {
        "body": "Submitting a test comment"
    }
}
});
var apiURL = 'https://[subdomain].zendesk.com/api/v2/requests/[id].json';
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/v2/requests/" + id+ ".json",
     type: 'PUT',
     data: JSON.stringify(request),
     contentType: "application/json",
     success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
         alert("Success")
     },
     error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert(errorThrown);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Was able to figure it out using this.

```
"request": {
    "comment": {
        "body": "Submitting a test comment"
    }
}
});
var token = document.getElementsByName("csrf-token")[0].content;
var apiURL = 'https://[subdomain].zendesk.com/api/v2/requests/[id].json';
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/v2/requests/" + id+ ".json",
     type: 'PUT',
     data: JSON.stringify(request),
     contentType: "application/json",
     headers: {
         "X-CSRF-Token": token
     }
     success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
         alert("Success")
     },
     error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert(errorThrown);
     }
});
```